# Copy directories without files from /etc to other directories

Tags: command-line

I want to copy all /etc directories without the files inside of them to other directories. There's another condition that they must start with a, b or c just from the first level.

I tried this:

```
user@system:/etc$ find . -maxdepth 1 -name "[abc]*" -type d -exec cp {} $HOME/bases2/p01 \;

cp: -r not specified; omitting directory './alternatives'
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory './ca-certificates'
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory './binfmt.d'
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory './apt'
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory './cron.monthly'
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory './chatscripts' 
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory './apm'
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory './cups'
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory './cron.d'
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory './apport'
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory './alsa'
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory './cracklib'
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory './cron.hourly'
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory './cron.daily'
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory './acpi'
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory './cron.weekly'
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory './cupshelpers'
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory './brltty'
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory './avahi'
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory './console-setup'
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory './bluetooth'
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory './bash_completion.d'
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory './chromium.d'
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory './apparmor.d'
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory './apparmor'
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory './calendar'
```

What does mean "-r not specified"? Which would be the correct way?

I'm new here and I'm learning Linux.

Answer (score 0):

The error "-r not specified" is given by the `cp` command. You're pointing it to directories that include sub-directories ("-r" is for "recursive") and it won't copy those unless you tell it explicitly to do so with that switch.

To find empty directories, use:

```bash
find . –type d -empty
```